# Xamarin jar binding error: Class does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, android, binding, xamarin

I am trying to create an Android Java binding library with Xamarin. I have the following error:

> Error CS0535: 'EU.mypackage.MyClass' does not implement interface member 'EU.MyPackage.IProgressableTask.DoProgress(params Java.Lang.Object[])' (CS0535)

this is the java code:

```
public class MyClass extends  Thread implements ProgressableTask<Integer>{
//some code here
@Override
public void doProgress(Integer... value) {
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
      msg.arg1 = progress;
      msg.arg2 = value[0];
      try {
        mHandler.send(msg);
        //System.out.println("SENT MESSAGE");
      } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
            HiEngageTracker.trackEvent(e1.getStackTrace()[0].toString(), context);
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
      } 


}
```

Please, could you help solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the Issue by adding this line in the Metadata.xml file:

```
<attr
path="/api/package[@name='eu.mypackage']/class[@name='MyClass']/method[@name='doProgress']/parameter[@type='java.lang.Integer...']" name="type">java.lang.Object[]</attr>
```

Now it compiles.